# Default value for @Input is overwritten by `undefined` in test wrapper

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following input on my component:

```
@Input()
someThing: string = 'm'; // default value
```

In my test I have defined it as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-wrapper-component',
  template: `
    <app-my-component someThing="someThing" />
  `
})
class TestWrapperComponent {
  someThing; // this needs to be defined, otherwise the template above won't recognize it
}
```

In this case `someThing` is `undefined`. And my component now renders with `someThing = undefined`.

How can I make sure that the @Input is the default value 'm' in the case of undefined or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, got it. Looks like setting it using `@Input` decorator isn't the way to go, but rather:

```
export class MyComponent implements Oninit, AfterContentInit {
  private defaultValue: any = 'm';

  @Input()
  someThing: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.something || this.defaultValue);
  }
```

This way, `this.something` is used when defined, otherwise the fallback is `this.defaultValue`.